# How to synchronize Data with a ServerDatabase?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My application should be syncronized with a ServerDB to collect some Data all users input.

How to do that in android? Through xml and evaluating these through self writen queries? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good thread for you [How to communicate with server's database from android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241533/how-to-communicate-with-servers-database-from-android-phone)

Basically, you should not use a JDBC / SQL connection directly as it doesn't suit mobile needs. But you build a web service your database on the server and communicate through the service to update your database and get refreshed data from it.

Comment: thx for your answer. After a lot og thinking I came up with another solution: it would be to build a web app and optimize it for mobile

Comment: why not ? The only difference can be in term of user experience. A native app is often more confortable and faster than a web app for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SampleSyncAdapter sample app.

Android apps can sync their content provider with a web-based database using the SyncAdapter class, which handles many of the details of scheduling and running synchronization. Sync adapters will try to avoid conflicting with each other, they won't run when the network is unavailable, and the user can configure them from the Accounts settings.

Even if your app is the only one using the mobile database, you should use a content provider, to allow the system to manage interaction between the db and the web.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php